# How to make every Laravel URL have parameter

Tags: php, laravel, routes

So I want to create admin page,

The result I want is like this

> foo.com/admin/anthony
>
> foo.com/admin/anthony/dologin
>
> foo.com/admin/anthony/index

I tried using this routes

> Route::any('admin/{username}', 'adminController@login'):
>
> Route::any('admin/{username}/login', 'adminController@dologin');

I want to use every username parameter in admin page, but wont redeclare every page.

Answer (score 0):

you can create group of route in laravel, below is the example which might help you.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin/{username}'], function () {
    Route::get('login', 'adminController@dologin');
});
```

Let me know if this doesn't work for you.

Comment: It doesn't work, I still need to pass the username parameter. Ah I think this is impossible to not pass parameter if parameter is required :(

Comment: Yes, But if you want to use that variable post login you can use session to store value. But in your case it seems you are trying yo user it throughout the process.